# In Unity, is it possible to resolve a type from its type alias?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I've registered several types in Unity and given them type aliases as follows:

```
<typeAliases>
   <typeAlias alias="MyType" type="foo.bar.MyType, foo.bar" />
</typeAliases>
```

Is it possible to resolve these types by from the container using the aliased name (as opposed to by type), along the lines of:

```
var myType = container.ResolveByTypeAlias("MyType")
```

I can't see any way to do this, but wondered if I've missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, aliases exist only in the XML configuration.  i.e. they only exist at configuration type.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660933(v=pandp.20).aspx](http://bit.ly/JAm6jH) details this

> Aliases only exist at configuration time. They are not available at
>   run time.

Answer (score -1):

For my reference in the future -

If you are trying to resolve a type by using a named parameter, this can be done by using the Resolve(string name)
*Returns a concrete instance of the type that is registered for the generic type T and has the specified name.*

Comment: This isn't really related - the question is about whether you can access a type by it's alias as specified in xml config, as opposed to being able to resolve a type using the "name" parameter that was specified at registration time.

Comment: fair enough. The only reason i put it here is that a\